# Exclude Outer Island From SF Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, geospatial

I'm trying to exclude all the outer islands from a Indonesia Jakarta sf data frame (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vBq3vi9Kl-sXlIapQYrQccIVpkWXBMbb/view) and just retain the mainland for analysis. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In PROVINSI column, all data is DKI JAKARTA. I need little more information about data, especially 'DESA', 'KAB_KOTA', 'KECAMATAN', 'DESA_KELIR' and your purpose. Among data, which column do I need to consider for your purpose?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your posts after other people have taken the trouble to research and post an answer to your question. It would be much better if you'd take the time to follow the advice of the above comments and improve your question, so it might be of more use to others.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of experimenting seems to show that the mainland is all the features where `KAB_KOTA` is not `KEPULAUAN SERIBU`:

```
library(sf)
map = st_read("./BATAS_DESA_DESEMBER_2019_DUKCAPIL_DKI_JAKARTA.shp")

plot(map[map$KAB_KOTA!="KEPULAUAN SERIBU","KAB_KOTA"])
```

[image]

So you can get the mainland with:

```
mainland = map[map$KAB_KOTA!="KEPULAUAN SERIBU",]
```

Maybe one of the other 162 columns in this data is a single value for all the mainland features, but this seems correct and simple enough.